# Setting up tables for multiplier save operations in chronoforms

Tags: joomla, chronoforms

I am trying to set up multiplier in one of the forms. I have followed all the articles and I think I have the setting right regarding multiplier content. Now I need help with setting up two tables to save the data.

My first table will have all the fields and a foreign key which will point to multiplier data.

Form design:
[image: This image shows the form design]
Setup:
[image: This image shows the setup]

Answer (score 1):

Your first table can be set up using the settings in the ChronoForms Create Table dialogue, but you should leave out the columns for the three multiplier elements.

The second table needs to have columns for an auto-incremented primary key plus a column for the record id from the first table plus the three multiplier elements. You could create this from the Create Table dialogue by manually editing the settings, or, if you prefer, you can use PHPMySQL or some similar database editor.

Bob